# Bound javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Alright my basic question is how do I simulate a button click in javascript.

I know I have to use document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click(); but this doesn't seem to call the onClientClick javascript function as well.

Enviorment:

I am using ASP.NET with C# and javascript.

What happened:
I have an input text area and I want to make sure that users must enter a character before the submit button is enabled.  I was able to do this with onkeypress="validateTxt();" which then called this function

```
 function validateTxt() {
    var input = document.getElementById("<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>").value;
    //Need a min of 3 characters
    if(input.length > 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

The only problem though is doesn't register backspace.

To solve this I found this online

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementsByName('txtUserName')[0].onkeydown = function (event) {
        if (event === undefined) event = window.event; // fix IE 
        if (event.keyCode === 8)
         validateTxt();
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
        }
        };
```

Now whenever the user presses the backspace my javascript function is called. This worked great up until I found out that when I press enter from the text area it wouldn't call my javascript function.

Here is all of the relevant code...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function InformUser()
{
    window.document.getElementById("loadingMessageDIV").style.display = "block";
   <%=Page.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSubmit as Control)%>
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;
}

function validateTxt() {
    var input = document.getElementById("<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>").value;
    //Need a min of 3 characters
    if(input.length > 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;
    }
}

</script>
```

Here is the text area + javascript bounding function

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Font-Size="11pt" onkeypress="validateTxt();"></asp:TextBox>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //We bind the textbox to this function and whenever the backspace key is pressed it will validateTxt
                document.getElementsByName('txtUserName')[0].onkeydown = function (event) {
                    if (event === undefined) event = window.event; // fix IE 
                    if (event.keyCode === 8)
                        validateTxt();
                    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
                    }
                }; 
            </script>
```

Here is the submit button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="InformUser();" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
                            Text="Login" Font-Bold="True" Enabled="True" />
                        <script type="text/javascript">
//Disable the button until we have some actual input
                            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;
                        </script>
```

So to recap it does press the button, but it fails to disable it as well.  I even tried to call the InformUser directly when the user presses enter and then press the button, but that didn't work either.

I know it has something to do with how I bound the javascript function to the text area because when I take it out it works.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If what you're really trying to do is enable/disable the submit button based on the amount of text in the text area, then it would be simplest just to check the length every time it's changed.

Would you be able to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)? If you can, it's a trivial problem, as jQuery normalises keyboard events so you don't have to worry about different browsers raising different events.

As a simple experiment, I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkRCU/) with this HTML:

```
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
<label id="count" />
```

and this JavaScript:

```
$('#txt').keyup(function () {
    $('#count').text($('#txt').val().length);
});
```

On every [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) (I used keyup rather than keydown or keypress as keyup fires after the text has been modified) the length is updated. This registers normal keys, backspace, delete, enter, etc, and works in FF and IE8.

In your case, you'd obviously change the function to enable/disable the submit button.

Comment: just note that a user can hit enter and the length will be 1 and the user will be able to submit

Comment: True - that's the same as the original code. If you wanted to get around that then you could rip out any carriage returns before checking the length: $('#count').text($('#txt').val().replace(/[\n\r]/g, '').length);